# Can't delete generic admin acct in Vista after using PCLogin for password recovery

Tags: windows-vista, passwords

I used pclogin to recover my admin password in Vista. It worked great. But I now have a generic admin acct listed on my sign-in screen and it doesn't require a password! Anybody that wants to can click on it and they are in to my pc!  How do I remove it? I have tried to remove the acct and it won't go away. Do I need to edit my registry?

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove it because it's built in. The easiest option is to disable it.

Run command prompt as administrator and execute the following command:

```
net user Administrator /active:no
```

When you log out you should no longer see the Administrator account as an option on the logon screen.